# Kafka consumer not able to read msg?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to read messages from a Kafka topic using Python's KafkaConsumer, but I am encountering an issue where the consumer is not able to retrieve any messages. Here is the code that I am using

I have checked in remote machine in the topic msg is exits also I am able to produce msg in kafka vm but not from python but topic is creating from python.

my consumer code:

```
#kafka version3.4
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'study1',
    bootstrap_servers=['{remote.azure.vm.ip}:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='kjalkdjhgfofgsf',consumer_timeout_ms=10000,
    value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')
)

for message in consumer:
    print(message.value)
```

after this I am getting log that accept connection but no msg

Comment: Are you changing the value of `group_id` every time you run the code?  By default, Kafka won't send messages that your consumer  object has already seen.

Comment: yes evrytime changing

Comment: DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=ip:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('ip', 9092)]> Response 4 (57.9073429107666 ms): MetadataResponse_v1(brokers=[(node_id=0, host='ip', port=9092, rack=None)], controller_id=0, topics=[(error_code=0, topic='study1', is_internal=False, partitions=[(error_code=0, partition=0, leader=0, replicas=[0], isr=[0])])])
DEBUG:kafka.cluster:Updated cluster metadata to ClusterMetadata(brokers: 1, topics: 1, groups: 1)
this my log but after this I am not getting msg

Comment: one more thing I am not able to send msg using producer but it is connecting to kafka. as I can see topic is creating automatically but msg is not going to topic I have checked in kafka server.

Comment: Hi team please help me to resolve this issue I am using python 3.9 and kafka3.4

Comment: I resolved this issue by changing the private ip to public ip of advertised.listeners properties in server.properties file and issue is resolved.